# Flask application with gunicorn Docker container exits instantly

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "wsgi:app"]
```

**docker command:**
`docker run -it -d --name api -p 5000:5000 test_api:latest`

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
class Source(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'test': True}
api.add_resource(Source, '/')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from app.run import app
if __name__ =='__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: Remove the `-d` from the command line and you might see an error message. I suspect the import line in `wsgi.py`.

Comment: `wsgi.py` seems redundant. If you want to retain it, the import should probably be `from app import run`. You don't include the `requirements.txt` file but presumably it includes `Flask`, `flask_restful` and `gunicorn`. This works for me.

Comment: Thanks :). It works

Comment: yes, requirements include Flask, flask_restful and gunicorn. I will remove wsgi.py. Thanks..